# Generated target files after build doesn't contain all the compiled classes that must have been there

Tags: java, netbeans, maven-2, maven

While building the project, the console shows that the source packages were compiled(the one inside `px10` package)

However if I see the target files generated, none of the classes are there from source package.

1. tried `clean & build` several times but doesnt help
2. cleared the netbeans cache from `.../var/cache/`

Here is the log generated while building the web app

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building ABCApp Java EE 6 Webapp 1.0
------------------------------------------------------------------------

[antrun:run]
Executing tasks
Executed tasks

[resources:resources]
Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Copying 13 resources

[compiler:compile]
File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Compiling 81 source files to C:\dev\ABCApp\target\classes
px10/BusinessLayer/LOBERs/connect.java:[248,38] ';' expected
px10/BusinessLayer/User/User_2.java:[127,52] '.class' expected

[resources:testResources]
Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Copying 1 resource

[compiler:testCompile]
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[surefire:test]
Surefire report directory: C:\dev\ABCApp\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0


[war:war]
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [ABCApp] in [C:\dev\ABCApp\target\ABCApp]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [C:\dev\ABCApp\src\main\webapp]
Webapp assembled in [1841 msecs]
Building war: C:\dev\ABCApp\target\ABCApp.war
Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')

[install:install]
Installing C:\dev\ABCApp\target\ABCApp.war to C:\dev\mavenRepository\w93\ABCApp\1.0\ABCApp-1.0.war
Installing C:\dev\ABCApp\pom.xml to C:\dev\mavenRepository\w93\ABCApp\1.0\ABCApp-1.0.pom
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 9.053s
Finished at: Tue Oct 04 11:49:46 IST 2011
Final Memory: 6M/15M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**This issue seems to be arising since I have deleted a folder named `classes` from inside `web-inf`  folder which I myself had created.**

Here is the effective POM for the project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>w93</groupId>
  <artifactId>ABCApp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>ABCApp Java EE 6 Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3_01</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3_01</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.30</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.M3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>java.net2</id>
      <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>jsf20</id>
      <name>Repository for library Library[jsf20]</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>prime-repo</id>
      <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>c:\dev\ABCApp\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>c:\dev\ABCApp\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>c:\dev\ABCApp\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>c:\dev\ABCApp\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>c:\dev\ABCApp\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>c:\dev\ABCApp\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>c:\dev\ABCApp\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>c:\dev\ABCApp\target</directory>
    <finalName>ABCApp</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <compilerArguments>
                <bootclasspath>${settings.localRepository}/javax/javaee-endorsed-api/6.0/javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\modules\jdk.boot.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\classes</bootclasspath>
              </compilerArguments>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
              <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <compilerArguments>
                <bootclasspath>${settings.localRepository}/javax/javaee-endorsed-api/6.0/javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\modules\jdk.boot.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\classes</bootclasspath>
              </compilerArguments>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
              <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArguments>
            <bootclasspath>${settings.localRepository}/javax/javaee-endorsed-api/6.0/javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\modules\jdk.boot.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\classes</bootclasspath>
          </compilerArguments>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <failOnError>false</failOnError>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile-protoc</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <mkdir dir="src/main/resources/protocolBuffers/compiled" />
                <path id="proto.path">
                  <fileset dir="src/main/proto">
                    <include name="**/*.proto" />
                  </fileset>
                </path>
                <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="proto.files" refid="proto.path" />
                <exec executable="src/main/resources/protocolBuffers/compiler/protoc" failonerror="true">
                  <arg value="--java_out=src/main/resources/" />
                  <arg value="-Ic:\dev\ABCApp/" />
                  <arg line="${proto.files}" />
                </exec>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>c:\dev\ABCApp\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>c:\dev\ABCApp\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>c:\dev\ABCApp\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>c:\dev\ABCApp\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>endorsed</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>sun.boot.class.path</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
              <compilerArguments>
                <bootclasspath>${settings.localRepository}/javax/javaee-endorsed-api/6.0/javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\modules\jdk.boot.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\classes</bootclasspath>
              </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: I am missing a point related to your final paragraph: what is the  path relative to the project root of such `classes` folder? And, you'd rather paste here the `clean compile` log, not the `test` one . A `mvn clean compile -X` output would be tops, if it is of manageable length.

Comment: path of `classes` was src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/. Inside this folder I placed some of the configuration files that were required for logging framework (`logback`). But since I moved these files somewhere else I simply deleted this directory. I dont operate `mvn` from command line but from the netbeans itself. The  log printed above is generated when i perform `clean & build`.

Comment: The information above is not sufficient to help you with your issue. You either need to include the `pom.xml` (better if you dump the Effective POM), and/or provide us with a more detailed trace as with `mvn clean compile -X`. Better the second one, if you say that some files do not make it to the /target folder.

Comment: I tried putting here the `clean compile` output but that was too too big and thus I have put the effective POM . Let me know if any thing more is needed. should i put output of `mvn compile` ?

Comment: I believe `mvn clean compile` would be a more useful output than the one you got from netbeans. I am not a netbeans user but it is very unlikely that the problem depends on that IDE. Anyway, you would verify it easily by checking the /target content after running the above command line.

Comment: ohk.. i am trying to get `mvn clean compile` output. Yes I am looking at the /target only after running clean build & it was nt showing compiled classes from source packages. anyways I'll soon be back with `mvn clean compile` output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the issue was due to some of the uncompilable classes inside the source packages because of that none of classes were being copied to the `/target/classes/` folder. On removing the uncompilable source code I found it to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

maven does not place generated contents in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` folder.

By default (and from the pom snippet above), it places the compiled classes in `target/classes` folder.  In case of a war project, `maven war plugin` copies the classes to  `WEB-INF/classes` folder within the webapp.

So, in your case, check the following folders:

- C:\dev\ABCApp\target\classes
- C:\dev\ABCApp\target\ABCApp\WEB-INF\classes

Comment: yes Raghuram .. I have checked both folders but the compiled java classes  are nowhere.

Comment: Infact now I see that no java classes have been compiled

Comment: @Marcos. I see "Compiling 81 source files to C:\dev\ABCApp\target\classes" in your log above.  So something else is removing them before the build ends

Comment: yes... and if you see in my `pom.xml` there is an plugin `maven-antrun-plugin` that is automating the compilation of .proto files for protocol buffers. Those files are getting copied to `/classes` folder.

Comment: @Marcos. antrun is happening before compilation. Check the folders above after running mvn test to see if classes are retained.  If not, try mvn compile.  This will help isolate the problem

Comment: in both the cases, java classes are not compiled & just the protocol buffers generated folder(by `maven-antrun-plugin`) is there

Answer (score 1):

This also occurs with certain versions of the maven-compiler-plugin

The following fix resolved the issue for me and maven now correctly reports compiler errors.
With the commented version below, maven would build successfully despite uncompilable code.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <!--This version will happily build successfully when the code fails to compile-->
    <!--<version>3.1</version>-->
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If package not creating in classes folder while code building maven project with spring boot application.
This also occurs with certain versions of the maven-compiler-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <!--This version will happily build successfully when the code fails to compile-->
    <!--<version>3.1</version>-->
          <configuration>
                <!--<skipMain>true</skipMain>-->
                <skip>true</skip>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```