# Build is success but no source to compile

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am quite new to Maven/jenkins build. I am building my mule project and getting the following message.
[No source to compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAvvJ.jpg)

The source files are kept under src/main/java
[Source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZvXx.jpg)

I tried giving the source directory path in the pom.xml. Didn't help.

Can someone help me out with the same.
Thanx

Comment: are you running it from the same directory where pom.xml is?

Comment: yes. pom.xml and src directory are in the same base folder of project.

Comment: From your screenshot it is evident that `compiling 20 source files ...`, but `No sources to compile` is for your test classes.

Comment: check this link, may be it will helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644771/generated-target-files-after-build-doesnt-contain-all-the-compiled-classes-that

Comment: I think, issue was due to some of the uncompilable classes inside the source packages because of that none of classes were being copied to the /target/classes/ folder. On removing the uncompilable source code I found it to be working fine.

Comment: try to add **-x** to your MVN command , BTW , which command are you using ?

Comment: Thanx Guys. It worked. Removing the uncompatible class helped. Still wondering why no error was thrown. :)

Answer (score 0):

if possible can you share your pom.xml.
Additionally, check if your build-helper-maven-plugin have correct source code directories configured like below.

```html
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>add-resource</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>add-resource</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <resources>
        <resource>
         <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
         <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
         <directory>src/main/api/java/</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
         <directory>mappings/</directory>
        </resource>
       </resources>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
```